# Fonts with no CDN?

Tags: html, fonts, cdn

I try to load fonts via CDN, but requirements for a font do not have that. We are using Montserrat Light in some areas and my preference per Google fonts doesn't allow for the 'light' version. Instead, I found it [HERE](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/montserrat?q%5Bterm%5D=montserrat&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y), but no CDN capability. So how do you all deal with this for your users without having them having to download or whatever. Looking for suggestions?

Thanks much.

Comment: CDN or no CDN, if you want a font which isn't installed on the user's system, then it has to be downloaded.

Comment: So, what Quentin is trying to say, is that you need to host it somewhere. This doesn't have to be a specialized CDN. It can be on your own web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CDN is just "someone else's site" that you use for efficiency reasons. If no CDN is available, the obvious choice to put the data for online retrieval is "the same place you've put the rest of your website": just like how you have .html and .css files sitting in directories that are accessible to the outside world, you add your font file(s) in similar fashion and then just load them by relative URL.